# Coloring Edges in graph according to their vertexes color

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

1. I working in mathematica and have a graph that every vertex is in a different color, i want to coloring the edges. for example: if two vertex in the same color, the edge will be in some color, and so on for all the edges with this property.
2. In general, how can i get the color of vertex?

Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be easier to work with the data used to create the `Graph` then to operate on the graph object itself.  Can you explain in much more detail what you are trying to do. Directives for coloring edges/vertices are given by `EdgeStyle` and `VertexStyle` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how to generate the graph, assuming you have access to the input:

```
 g = Select[
         Union@Table[ 
          RandomInteger[{1, 10}] -> RandomInteger[{1, 10}], {35}],
            ! Equal @@ # &];
 colors = Table[ 
    i -> RandomChoice[ {Red, Blue, Green, Orange} ] ,
             {i, (Union@Flatten[List @@@ g])}];
 Graph[g,
   VertexStyle -> colors,
   EdgeStyle -> ((# -> (#[[1]]/.colors )) & /@ 
     Select[g,(#[[1]]/.colors) == (#[[2]]/.colors ) & ]) ]
```

[image]

If you only have the graph object and need to extract the style data that will be a bit of a chore.

Comment: Thanks! The code was very helpful and understandable !

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier to do with the property mapping functionality of [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

Generate a graph with random colours:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20},
  VertexStyle -> {_ :> RandomChoice[{Orange, Darker@Green, Lighter@Blue}]},
  EdgeStyle -> Thick,
  VertexSize -> Medium
 ]
```

[image]

Load the package:

```
<<IGraphM`
```

Do the mapping:

```
IGEdgeMap[
 If[First[#] === Last[#], First[#], None] &,
 EdgeStyle -> IGEdgeVertexProp[VertexStyle],
 g
]
```

[image]

Explanation:

`IGEdgeVertexProp[VertexStyle]` is a function that extracts the VertexStyle of the endpoints of all edges, as a list.

```
IGEdgeVertexProp[VertexStyle][g]
```

[image]

`IGEdgeMap[f, prop -> fun, g]` will apply the function `f` to each element of the above list (returned by `fun[g]`), and store each result in the edge property `prop`.

I find this style of working with properties to be very easy for graph styling, property transformations, copying properties, etc.

There is also `IGEdgeProp` and `IGVertexProp` for extracting edge and vertex properties, respectively, and `IGVertexMap` for mapping a function onto vertex properties.